# Matching partial text at the end of a string in Google Sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have [data in a Google spreadsheet](https://pastebin.com/kyAmzER1) that I need to match to their standard country codes. For e.g. `Greater Chicago Area` would be `US`. For all cells that need to be marked US, they seem to end with the word `Area`. For all other countries, they end with their country names.
I tried the following formula but it does not seem to work -

`=IFS(ISNUMBER(FIND("Area",A64)), "US", ISNUMBER(FIND("*United Kingdom",A64)), "UK")`.

Is there a way to match partial text at the end of the string?

Comment: You can use `=right(A34, 4)="Area". But that will still leave you with parts of Canada in US.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the answer if you just wanted it by name, I didn't use country codes but you can easily just do a find replace search OR define a vlookup from another range.

**Answer Spreadsheet with Formulas Listed in Column Header -** 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KOYWwqY_T8aG0USy5POVLjAdl99N2PrwWs5mpQAruRg/edit?usp=sharing

**Steps:**

1. Paste Region Data from your pastebin
2. Does the string Ends in "Area" using `=right(A2,4)="Area"` 
   // Let's us know almost all cases that are US
3. Find Comma Index using `=find(",",A2)` 
   // Let's us find last word in array
4. Find Char Right of Comma using `=LEN(A2)-C2` 
   // Tells how many letters are to the right of the comma (the last word + one space)
5. Subtract 1 for the space using `=D2-1` 
   // You can use `Trim()` for non standardized data but for your use case -1 works fine
6. Everything Right of the Comma using `=right(A2,E2)` 
   // The last word
7. Country Name using `=if(B2,"United States of America",F2)` 
   // If it ends in area set to US otherwise set it to last word in string
8. Special Case Handling using 
   `=if(ISERR(F2),G2,if(G2="TN","United States",if(G2="TN","United States of America",if(G2="Zhejiang, China","China",if(F2="Canada Area","Canada",G2)))))` 
   // Your special cases that need to be overridden.
9. Vlookup for country code
   `=vlookup(H2,'Country Codes'!A:B,2,false)` 
   /// Will find the country code in column S of searched range based on KEY provided.

If you need to clean this up for a presentation you can just replace **ALL** cell references with the formula in that cell until you nest all the way back to just column A.

Comment: [Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37297307) of the ```VLOOKUP``` implementation @NathanielKam was mentioning for substutuying the country names by country codes.

Comment: ooh that is very useful thanks @MateoRandwolf, I will add it into the public spreadsheet sample to complete the tutorial :)

Comment: This is incredibly useful! Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

Your formula seems to be okay. Please try and place this FIND condition at the last, after checking for every other country code.

```
ISNUMBER(FIND("Area",A64)), "US"
```

[image]

Comment: It works yes, but it matches `Area` irrespective of where it is. If it finds it first, then it tags to that country code. Because of this entries such as `Lisbon Area, Portugal` will also be marked as `US`.

Comment: Even avoiding that would give you e.g. Montreal in US since the dataset includes `Montreal, Canada Area`. You should check your source for more information, or go through the edge cases manually (gulp)

Comment: Edited my formula. "Area" is not unique to "US" Code. IFS returns the first true statement. Have you considered using SEARCH formula. SEARCH accepts wildcards

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this single formula

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(REGEXREPLACE(
                      REGEXREPLACE(A2:A,"Canada Area","Canada"),
                               " Area$|, TN$",", US")))
```

[image]

**How does the formula work?**

The inner `REGEXREPLACE` finds the expression `Canada Area` within the text and replaces it with just `Canada`.
Then, the outer `REGEXREPLACE` finds where the very last `Area` or `TN` string and replaces them with `, US` *(we can further enrich the formula with more conditions if necessary)*
Finally the combination of `INDEX` and `IFERROR` expands our formula to the whole range excluding errors (which are now returned as empty cells).
As for the regex symbols used, `$` defines the end of a line and `|` the `OR` statement.

Functions used:

- [`INDEX`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242)
- [`IFERROR`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304)
- [`REGEXREPLACE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245)